# Why does Web Platform installer try to repair itself every 40 mins?

Tags: windows-server-2008, chef, web-platform-installer

I'm seeing Web Platform installer do a repair/reinstall on my win 2008 r2 server (Build: 7601: Service Pack 1).

Web Platform installer has been initially installed on this machine via chef (the 'iis' and 'webpi' community cookbooks).

Now Web PI seems to have started reinstalling itself at ~40 min intervals, ultimately causing IIS to restart and disrupt my web apps on the machine.

I've tried to investigate the event logs, which do nothing to explain why this is happening / how I can prevent it.

I got a bit more info by turning on verbose logging for the MS Installer, but nothing is jumping out: http://pastebin.com/5yRYnQ0e

**What would trigger Web Platform Installer to attempt to reinstall, and how would I prevent it?**

Answer (score 0):

The Google keywords are `msi self repair`. They uncover vast depths of related issues. The answer to this question contains detailed roundup of possible causes for self-repair: [How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair)

In addition, the regular interval you mention could be related to the Group Policy propagation or some scheduled tasks running, that cause files\registry entries to be modified and trigger self-repair.

To rule out scheduled tasks, you could try my [Windows Task Scheduler chart script](https://superuser.com/questions/856244/windows-task-scheduler-chart/885017#885017) and see if there some task running in the mentioned intervals.

Also, this article provides nice step-by-step debugging of MSI self-repair issue: [Solving MSI self-repair issues in ThinApp](http://blogs.vmware.com/thinapp/2012/04/solving-msi-self-repair-issues-in-thinapp.html)